# How to route an angular 2 component in electron?

Tags: angular, electron

I am new to angular and electron development.

I did the project in ASP.net and angular and there I could change the components by changing the path like this:

```
...
imports: [

        RouterModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'client', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'client', component: ViewClientsComponent },
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
            { path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent },


            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'client' }
        ])
    ]

...
```

What is the equivalent of this in electron? Since there aren't any paths and I don't want to open a new window for every component. Is there any way to switch the components on my main window?